# Adjusting top margin of web element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

On my page http://bit.ly/KseVxs I have a floating element that stays at one place when I scroll the page down.

How can I adjust css so it would show on the top of page? Right now it shows with extra space at the top ( see attached screenshot). In other words I need it to behave like a similar element on this page http://bit.ly/LsWPaC , it utilizes the same exact script and css.

[image]

Comment: I think your main problem is that you're using tables for layout...The markup is a bit of a mess. I would think about starting over.

Comment: It's impossible to help you if we can't see your page,with your CSS, your extra space and your scripts...

Comment: Your problem is better than the example you're copying. Their script has the follow obscured by my browser window. Doesn't look like it was debugged for firefox.

Comment: @JotaBe There is a link to the page in a post, in case you didn't find here it is again http://bit.ly/KseVxs

Comment: @elclanrs I tried to do it with div layout, unfortunately since I couldn't get a div to be height:100%, I had to go with a 2 column  table

Comment: @kristinachilds looks fine in my firefox, I always test in chrome, FF and IE

Comment: i'm on mac. perhaps that's why? it definitely sits higher than it should. the top half of the header in that div is too high, making it look like there's a negative margin of about 50px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

Have you tried changing the offset value in the plugin configuration? e.g.

```
$( '#floater3' ).scrollFollow({
speed: 500,
offset: 0
});
```

When I checked just now the offset is set to 165px.

I also notice that a `br` is the first element in your scrolling object. That is going to add some additional padding above the blue 'call' box, which may not be desirable.

Comment: yes, I figured it out on my own and was able to fix the issue by adjusting the offset, for some reason the offset worked differently for chrome than for FF and IE so I had to throw some browser recognition into mix and have different offset values for each of them. I am gonna mark you answer as correct anyway, because it was right on the money :)

Answer (score 0):

In your html look for:

```
<div id="floater2" ...
```

Cut the whole div tag from its starting div to its closing div tag.

Then look for this html block:

```
<a href="mold-coupons-free" rel="nofollow">
  <img src="images/coupon-free-inspection-town.gif" width="236" height="109" border="0" alt="FREE Mold Inspection coupon">
</a>
```

Paste the code that you removed immediately after the </a> tag, so it would look like this:

```
<a href="mold-coupons-free" rel="nofollow">
  <img src="images/coupon-free-inspection-town.gif" width="236" height="109" border="0" alt="FREE Mold Inspection coupon">
</a>
<div id="floater2" ... </div>
```

Comment: I nested it the way you suggested but got the same result in Chrome (big whitespace on top), but also now its not working in FF and IE and not showing on scroll

Comment: Tried it in chrome web developer only, and I saw that the spacing improved. Probably did not work on other browsers. Anyway, just an alternative if you needed